# What PHP Netbeans IDE configuration results in more productive development?

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans6.8

For example I use Netbeans for PHP and have started to integrate PHPUnit & XDebug as part of my normal setup. What other plugins/modifications to Netbeans default setup can be more productive and useful.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My most used macro bound to Ctrl-;

```
";" delete-previous caret-end-line ";" jump-list-last-edit jump-list-last-edit
```

This puts a semicolon at the end of the current line without moving your cursor

Two custom key mappings I use most

- Ctrl+PERIOD mapped to Select Line
- Ctrl+COMMA to Select Word

These are not PHP specific, but it does make me more productive in developing PHP scripts.